# Cannot switch to another class when using emacs ebrowse

Tags: c++, emacs, elisp

I have been going through the emacs ebrowse *info* pages learning how to use it. I have hit a snag though. I am upto the "Member Buffers -> Switching Classes" page in which is states that I can swap classes using the "C c" key combination. Whenever I try to change to another class in the source tree it just spits out this error:

```
"ebrowse-ts-member-functions: ebrowse-ts-member-functions accessing a non-ebrowse-ts"
```

Has anyone seen this before? I couldn't find anything about it on google. I should mention that I have my source code in multiple directories. I used

```
find . -name '*.cc' -or -name '*.h' | ebrowse
```

on the top-level of my directory structure. Could this be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think not. I tested it with a project distributed over several directories and I can reproduce this error: It occurs only when I use 'C c' in a member-buffer and select a Class that is referenced in the project, but is provided by a library and therefore the source not part of the Tree.
If I close the member-buffer and reopen it with 'L v' from the tree-buffer I can switch classes again.